# How to make it so your player can jump every n seconds

Tags: c#, timer

I want to run this every 2 seconds

i dont know how to make a timer :(

```
        {
            transform.Translate(0f, 10f * Time.deltaTime, 0f);
        }
```

Comment: This is winforms?

Comment: Is it a web application or WindowsForm application? Did you read about Timer control for Windows Forms on Msdn? Did you try to use it?

Answer (score 0):

May be this could help you:

1. Declare the Timer-type variable and initialize it with Timer object by passing 2   seconds interval time in constructor like this:

   ```
    System.Timers.Timer aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(2000);
   ```
2. Create an event handler to handle the event raised by the Timer after every two seconds, like this:

   ```
   public void OnTimedEvent(Object source, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
   {
       transform.Translate(0f, 10f * Time.deltaTime, 0f);
   }
   ```
3. Now, make the Timer's "Elapsed" property to point to the event handler you just created, like this:

   ```
   aTimer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
   ```
4. Now, call the Start() method on aTimer object to start the timer, like this:

   ```
   aTimer.Start();
   ```

For more details, visit [System.Timers (documentation)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer?view=netframework-4.8)